# Progruzzle & Colf

Tags: code-golf

Ever fancied creating cool twitter hashtags such as *#brexit* or *#brangelina*? this golf is for you.

---

Write a program that accepts two strings A & B as input and merges them according to the following algorithm:

1. let `n` be the number of vowels groups in A (e.g. `britain` has 2 vowels groups : `i` in position 3 and `ai` in position 5).

   - if n = 1 : truncate A starting at its first vowel group position (example: `bill` => `b`)
   - if n > 1 : truncate A starting at its `n-1`th vowel group position (example: `programming` => `progr`, `britain` => `br`)
2. remove all consonants at the beginning of B (`jennifer` =>
   `ennifer`)
3. concatenate the modified A & B

Vowels are `aeiou`; consonants are `bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz`.

### Input

You can assume the input strings are lowercase and contain at least one vowel and one consonant.

### Examples

```
brad + angelina      => brangelina
britain + exit       => brexit
ben + jennifer       => bennifer
brangelina + exit    => brangelexit
bill + hillary       => billary
angelina + brad      => angelad
programming + puzzle => progruzzle
code + golf          => colf
out + go             => o
```

Comment: New test case? `donald trump`.

Comment: These are essentially [portmanteaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau).

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54351/simple-portmanteau-with-longest-overlap)

Comment: @ETHproductions this seems to produce much different combinations, such as `Django + Angular = Djular`

Comment: What's "n-1th vowel group position"

Comment: @l4m2 Simple, the vowel group at the `n-1`th position. I'm not sure how to explain this better... how about this, it's the second to last vowel group.

Comment: @LyricLy Why `br[itain` while `brangel[ina`

Comment: @l4m2 in britain there are 2 vowels groups (`i` and `ai`), so you cut at the first one; in brangelina, there are 4 vowels groups (`a`, `e`, `i`, `a`) so you cut at the third one.

Comment: well so that's "remove the last two"

Comment: I've got a friend named `Brittany Elizabeth ...`, guess I'll call her `brelizabeth`! **Edit**: she does not appreciate such operation... exiting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Ruby, <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 40 + 1 = 41 bytes

+1 byte for `-p` flag. Takes space-separated input on STDIN.
-1 byte thanks to Martin Ender
-2 bytes thanks to histocrat

```ruby
sub /([aeiou]+([^aeiou]*)){,2} \g<2>/,""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX3@Yqhq1YrBdfij1SFiZ3GkXQS0gRsxV83VnxsLgfO4Yakp5zHpKEpWyR26bgu29OHVlV1r7cPOJjddt/URZGzDtgBiiHLgkoHjsgCdOOoNAlcSYR7Cov5RV/J1sJlGQyT@qv3m/LBmYDDwGLAp3m2BOrsOgLjbK9cigs8nY/sZMwb/wI)

### GNU sed, <s>39</s> 37 + 1 = 38 bytes

+1 byte for `-E` flag. Takes space-separated input on STDIN.
-1 byte thanks to Martin Ender

```
s/([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){,2} [^aeiou]*//
```

[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=cy8oW2FlaW91XStbXmFlaW91XSopeywyfSBbXmFlaW91XSovLw&input=YnJhZCBhbmdlbGluYQpicml0YWluIGV4aXQKYmVuIGplbm5pZmVyCmJyYW5nZWxpbmEgZXhpdApiaWxsIGhpbGxhcnkKYW5nZWxpbmEgYnJhZApwcm9ncmFtbWluZyBwdXp6bGUgCmNvZGUgZ29sZgpvdXQgZ28&args=LUU)

Not posting this as a separate answer because it is literally the same solution.

Comment: Nice regex! Mind if I use part of it in my JS answer?

Comment: Sure, go crazy.

Comment: You can golf the regex a bit more by capturing the `[^aeiou]` as a subexpression: `/([aeiou]+([^aeiou]*)){,2} \g<2>/`

Comment: @histocrat Thanks! I forgot you can do that with numbered groups (i.e. you don't need to name the group).

Comment: [Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7427/42899)

Comment: Does the `p` flag essentially add `ARGV.join(" ").` to the beginning of the code?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes No, it doesn't do anything with `ARGV`. Per `man ruby`, the `-n` flag "Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your script, which makes it iterate over file name arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`. `while gets; ... end`," and the `-p` flag "Acts mostly same as `-n` switch, but print the value of variable `$_` at the each end of the loop." Here's a good blog post on the topic: https://robm.me.uk/ruby/2013/11/20/ruby-enp.html

Comment: I did, I just misread the last bit. Hence why I deleted my comment. Thanks for the response! (Also, I just looked up how that works -- `Kernel#sub` operates on `$_`, which was what I was trying to figure out)

Comment: Doesn't `-p` add 3 characters—the space after the command itself, the `-` and the `p`? Do we have some sort of ruling on how flags needed to run the thing are counted?

Comment: @Anko See "Special invocations" in [this answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/11261). TL;DR: Only count bytes in addition to the default invocation. The default invocation for Ruby is `ruby -e "..."`. For this it's `ruby -pe "..."`, so it only adds one byte.

Answer (score 12):

## MATL, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
t13Y2XJmFwhdl=fql_):)itJmYsg)h
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dDEzWTJYSm1Gd2hkbD1mcWxfKTopaXRKbVlzZylo&input=J3Byb2dyYW1taW5nJwoncHV6emxlJw)

**Explanation**

```
t       % Implicitly grab the input and duplicate it
13Y2    % Push the string literal 'aeiouAEIOU'
XJ      % Store this in clipboard J for later use
m       % Check which characters from the input are vowels (true for vowel)
Fwh     % Prepend FALSE to this logical array
dl=     % Compute the difference and find where we went from not-vowel to vowel
f       % Find the indices of these transitions
q       % Subtract 1 to get the location of the last consonant in each transition
l_)     % Get the next-to-last one of these
:)      % Grab the first string up to this location

% Now for the second component!

it      % Explicitly grab the input and duplicate
J       % Retrieve the string literal 'aeiouAEIOU' from clipboard J
m       % Find where the vowels are (true for vowel)
Ys      % Compute the cumulative sum along the array. The result will be 0
        % for all characters before the first vowel and non-zero after
g)      % Convert to logical and use this as an index so any characters
        % after the first value are retrieved

% Now to combine them

h       % Horizontally concatenate the first and second pieces together
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: I always upvote happy code

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>81</s> <s>73</s> 72 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to @Jordan, 1 thanks to @DavidConrad*

```
a=>b=>a.match(/.*?(?=(?:[aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2}$)/)+b.match(/[aeiou].*/)
```

Even though `.match` returns an array, `array+array` returns a string with the contents of the arrays concatenated (i.e. `[0]+[1]` returns `"01"`).

#### Test snippet

```js
f=a=>b=>console.log(a,"+",b,"=",a.match(/.*?(?=(?:[aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2}$)/)+b.match(/[aeiou].*/))
f("brad")("angelina")
f("britain")("exit")
f("ben")("jennifer")
f("brangelina")("exit")
f("bill")("hillary")
f("angelina")("brad")
f("programming")("puzzle")
f("code")("golf")
f("progruzzle")("colf")
f("out")("go")
```

```html
<input id=A value="super">
<input id=B value="chafouin">
<button onclick="f(A.value)(B.value)">Run</button>
```

Jordan's excellent Ruby solution would be 53 bytes in JS:

```
x=>x.replace(/([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*/,"")
```

Comment: Maybe could just throw out the match bit and use a replace?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That kinda feels like stealing Jordan's answer :/

Comment: You quite literally read my mind. And yeah, that's true

Comment: Currying `(a,b)=>` to `a=>b=>` saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
e€ØcT
Çµḟ‘-ị’
Ç⁸ḣ⁹ÑḢ⁹ṫ
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZeKCrMOYY1QKw4fCteG4n-KAmC3hu4vigJkKw4figbjhuKPigbnDkeG4ouKBueG5qw&input=&args=InByb2dyYW1taW5nIg+InB1enpsZSI)**

How?

```
e€ØcT    - Link 1, vowel indexes: s   e.g. "colouring"
  Øc     - yield vowels, "AEIOUaeiou"
e€       - in for each                     [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]
    T    - truthy indexes (1-based)        [2,4,5,7]

Çµḟ‘-ị’  - Link 2, n-1th or only vowel group index start - 1: s
 µ       - monadic chain separation
Ç        - call last link (1) as a monad   [2,4,5,7]
   ‘     - increment                       [3,5,6,8]
  ḟ      - filter out                      [2,4,7]
    -    - -1
     ị   - index value                     [4]
               (Jelly is 1-based and has modular indexing,
                so the last but one item is at index -1,
                and when there is only 1 item in the list it is also at index -1)
      ’  - decrement                       [3]

Ç⁸ḣ⁹ÑḢ⁹ṫ - Main link: a, b                      e.g. "colouring", "pencils"
Ç        - call last link (2) as a monad with a      [3]
 ⁸       - link's left argument, a
  ḣ      - head a[:y]                                "col"
   ⁹  ⁹  - link's right argument, b
    Ñ    - call next link (1) as a monad                          [2,5]
     Ḣ   - pop head                                               [2]
       ṫ - tail b[y-1:]                                           "encils"
         - implicit print                            "colencils"
```

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell v2+, 76 bytes

```
param($n,$m)($n-replace'([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2}$')+($m-replace'^[^aeiou]*')
```

Apparently this is a popular regex ... ;-)

Uses the `-replace` operator to pull off the appropriate pieces, then string-concatenates the results together. Adds on a `$` to the first to ensure we pull the end of the string, and adds a `^` to the second to ensure we pull off the front of the string.

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 35 bytes

```
([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAooW2FlaW91XStbXmFlaW91XSopezEsMn0gW15hZWlvdV0qCg&input=YnJhZCBhbmdlbGluYQpicml0YWluIGV4aXQKYmVuIGplbm5pZmVyCmJyYW5nZWxpbmEgZXhpdApiaWxsIGhpbGxhcnkKYW5nZWxpbmEgYnJhZApwcm9ncmFtbWluZyBwdXp6bGUKY29kZSBnb2xmCm91dCBnbw) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Simply removes all matches of the regex on the first line.

Comment: Any plans to add vowel and non-vowel classes? ;-)

Comment: @ETHproductions If I can ever be bothered to implement my own regex flavour (or at least tokenise it so that it can be transpiled to .NET regex), sure! :P

Comment: Ruby can do pattern backreferences (same pattern that can match a different sequence of characters). These would be useful here. For example, matching parentheses are matched by `/^((\(\g<1>\))*)$/` in Ruby.

Comment: @JanDvorak Too bad Retina is written in .NET, huh? ;) I did consider bundling it with https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net so that you can switch flavours, but didn't get around to that yet, and some other features are increasingly relying on .NET-specific match behaviour.

Comment: Time to drop the .net specific behavior and rewrite everything in Ruby? Ruby is better anyways :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak And give up balancing groups? No way. :P I guess one day I'll have to write my own flavour that can do both balancing groups and pattern reuse. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Cinnamon Gum, 23 bytes

```
0000000: 64d3 884e 4ccd cc2f 8dd5 8e8e 8330 b434  d..NL../.....0.4
0000010: b108 d92b c0d9 00                        ...+...
```

[Try it online.](http://cinnamon-gum.tryitonline.net/#code=MDAwMDAwMDogNjRkMyA4ODRlIDRjY2QgY2MyZiA4ZGQ1IDhlOGUgODMzMCBiNDM0ICBkLi5OTC4uLy4uLi4uMC40CjAwMDAwMTA6IGIxMDggZDkyYiBjMGQ5IDAwICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgLi4uKy4uLg&input=YnJpdGFpbiBleGl0)

### Explanation

This decompresses to `d([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*)([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*)? [^aeiou]*`, which `d`eletes anything matching that regex. (Note that Jordan's golfier `d([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){,2} [^aeiou]*` compresses to 24 bytes due to the lack of repeated elements to compress.)

Comment: Would `d[aeiou]+[^aeiou]*[aeiou]*[^aeiou]* [^aeiou]*` be any shorter?

Comment: @ETHproductions I tried that, it was the same byte count :(

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 95 Bytes

```
$t="aeiou]";echo($p=preg_filter)("#([$t+[^$t*){1,2}$#","",$argv[1]).$p("#^[^$t*#","",$argv[2]);
```

with preg_match instead of preg_filter 110 Bytes

```
$t="aeiou]";($p=preg_match)("#(.*?)([$t+[^$t*){1,2}$#",$argv[1],$m);$p("#[$t.*#",$argv[2],$n);echo$m[1].$n[0];
```

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `{1,2}`.

Comment: @Titus more important was to eliminate the bug for 1 case and now I can try to golf it down

Comment: Use `$v=aeiou;` to save 3 more.

Comment: @Titus I had the same idea but with a little variant. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, 66 bytes

```
$ cat merge.lua
print(((...):gsub(("[]+[^]*[]*[^]*+[^]*"):gsub("]","aeiou]"),"")))
$ lua merge.lua brad+angelina
brangelina
$ lua merge.lua programming+puzzle
progruzzle
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 39 bytes

38, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `-e`

```
s/([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*//
```

[Hat tip.](/a/94538)

Comment: Same as the sed answer linked to within, but we may as well have it in Perl also.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 139 bytes

```
n=lambda a,b:a[:a.index(([l for l in[[l,"!"][i!=0and a[i-1]in v]for i,l in enumerate(a)]if l in v]*2)[-2])]+b[sorted([(b+v).index(c)for c in v])[0]:]
```

This one was hard.

[Check it out on repl.it](https://repl.it/DiK6/40)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 65 bytes

```
#X::((replace X (regex "([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*") ""))
```

---

This is basically a port of the JavaScript answer above, in my Lisp-ish functional programming language.

Example usage:

```
(
    % Note, you can define this as a function, or assign it to a variable
    % and use the call function instead.
    (def f #X::((replace X (regex "([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*") "")))
    (print (f "programming puzzle"))
)
```

No online interpreter yet. I'll provide one soon. It won't be difficult, my language is written in JavaScript.

Instead, this puzzle solution is implemented as a working example for my language. It can be run with the following command:

```
node run.js l_src/progruzzle-colf.lithp
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>111</s> 108 bytes

```haskell
v x=elem x"aeiou"
d=dropWhile
e=d v
k=d$not.v
r=reverse
f a|c<-e.k.e.k$a,""/=c=c|1<3=e.k$a
a!b=(r.f.r)a++k b
```

This non-regex solution turned out longer than expected. [Ideone it anyway.](https://ideone.com/REZWtG)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 45 bytes

```
gsub("([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*";"")
```

Nothing special, just a port of [msh210](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1976/msh210)'s perl solution to jq's PCRE.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LbsIwEEX3fMXI3fDKomwR/EhEpYEYM8iMg7HVlsKv19hhEoEXlu@5R1c@nhOUo7YeG0A22hKjgg9YrSEzAaOszItEAYlB/1AYnBL6XjMcNTPtte97icNCP/k@0tHXJbIWDvlC/9tLzyTCMFM@LkbHsBGj9c54PJ2IDbTxerVatK7ogJg712gwzu5F2OWnVC6G3Ah3Bd6SucTtWI1r1OTiZlZ/PR/Tyd/nfHGHIaulUpOU/l0byPElVRVHayviNoYcPH5XeT6HBw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
r/\v+\V*){1,2} \V*
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9cditcViopezEsMn0gXFYq&input=LW1SIFsKImJyYWQgYW5nZWxpbmEiLAoiYnJpdGFpbiBleGl0IiwKImJlbiBqZW5uaWZlciIsCiJicmFuZ2VsaW5hIGV4aXQiLAoiYmlsbCBoaWxsYXJ5IiwKImFuZ2VsaW5hIGJyYWQiLAoicHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgcHV6emxlIiwKImNvZGUgZ29sZiIsCiJvdXQgZ28iCl0=)

Direct port of [short JS solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94536/78410) which is in turn the port of [Jordan's Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94538/78410).

#### How it works

```
Ur/\v+\V*){1,2} \V*/

Ur    Replace on the input...
/\v+\V*){1,2} \V*/  this regex with empty string.
      \v == [AEIOUaeiou], \V == [^AEIOUaeiou], `g` flag is on by default in Japt
      so the uncompressed regex is roughly /([aeiou]+[^aeiou]*){1,2} [^aeiou]*/g.
```